# Insert empty option to QuerySetSelectField

Tags: python, flask, jquery-select2, mongoengine

I have a model like

```
class AppMetaForm(BaseForm):
    category = QuerySetSelectField('CATEGORY'), queryset=AppCategory.objects())
    .....
```

On UI I am using `select2` to make select box nicer. Now I want to add placeholder like '-select-' to each select box. Select2 supports placeholder, but it requires first empty option in this case. So I need to insert an empty record to category choices list. Unfortunately, category does not have`choices` member (because it is not a SelectField). Also, I cannot use parameter `allow_blank` with `placeholder` in field definition because it does not accepts blank records.

If I replace `QuerySetSelectField` with `SelectField` and populate it via query, set up `coerce` to `ObjectId`, it is working but I cannot insert empty value because it is sending to server and causing error "None is not ObjectId".

How can I achieve the desired behavior?

Answer (score 0):

Fast fix found. I still do not know how update choices on server side, I did it mostly on client. One note for server side - in template added attribute to field `data-placeholder="-select-"`

---

```
$('select[data-placeholder]').each(function() {

    //Check whether any option is `selected`, pseudoattribute `:selected` here is unacceptable
    var selected = $('option[selected]', this);
    if (!selected.length) {

        //Creating fake option with valid but fake ObjectId and select it. 
        //If form returned after validation it already has `selected` option and I will not add placeholder to select.
        var option = $('<option>', {
            html: $(this).attr('data-placeholder'),
            selected: 'selected',
            value: '000000000000000000000000'
        });

        //Add this option first
        $(this).prepend(option);
    }
});

//Initialise all select tags with `select2` widget
$('select', container).select2({
    minimumResultsForSearch: -1,
    width: 'element'
});
```